# Visual Studio 2012 mouse flicker

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, any time the mouse is over a Debug "Watch" or "Autos" Window, OR if the mouse is over a String Table, it flickers horribly on every update.  Trying to scroll down through the String Table is so painful - you can watch each item get repainted with the mouse flickering the whole time (I have to move the mouse out of the window and then page up and down with the keyboard).

This didn't happen with Visual Studio 2008.

Interestingly, it also does not happen when I Remote Desktop to the exact same computer, same Visual Studio 2012 install, and even the same project.

The "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available" setting has no affect one way or the other.